# Outlook Express ( Exchange server compatible ) alternative for Debian/Linux?

Tags: linux, microsoft-outlook, debian, software-rec

I could set it up on my Virtualbox XP partition, but is there any decent application not named Evolution ( it's just a very odd, weird buggy and unstable application IMO ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Mozilla Thunderbird**](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/) is exchange compatible.

Comment: It is kind of a pain setting it up though, I tried and selected IMAP and gave it the OWA URL, signed in with my credentials, tried a slew of options, the configuration is more of a pain though I knew this was gonna happen.